# Perl array unique elements

Tags: arrays, perl, split, numbers, uniq

I have a perl array like below and I have to extract the unique elements of this array. Is there an easy way to do this ?

```
Perl> print(Dumper(@uncurled_data))
$VAR1 = '100 200';
$VAR2 = '100 200';
$VAR3 = '300 400';
$VAR4 = '100 200';
$VAR5 = '100 200';
$VAR6 = '300 400';
$VAR7 = '300 400';
$VAR8 = '300 400';
```

When I do this, `keys { map { (split /\ /, $_)[0] => 1 } @uncurled_data }`, I'll have to do it twice ie, once for each element in the array. Is there any one/liner or simple way to do this ?

Desired output array with 4 elements `100, 200, 300, 400`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a list of what you want to make unique,

```
map { split } @uncurled_data
```

Then use the standard ways of finding the unique items.

```
use List::Util qw( uniq );
my @uniq = uniq map { split } @uncurled_data;
```

or

```
my %seen;
my @uniq = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } map { split } @uncurled_data;
```

Comment: Required output array with 4 elements 100, 200, 300, 400

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
my @uniq = sort keys %{+{map {$_ => 1;} map { split } @uncurled_data}};
```